# Enumerable for negative ranges

Tags: c#, python, range

In python we have a range that can produce for an array with negative integers too.

For example:

```
In[4]: range(-2, 2+1)
Out[4]: [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
```

Is there an equivalent system in C#; I am aware of IEnumerable method, but upon trying it I get the following output:

```
//Rextester.Program.Main is the entry point for your code. Don't change it.
//Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 for Microsoft (R) .NET Framework 4.5

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
            int half_window = 2;
            var mySeq1 = Enumerable.Range(-2, 2+1).ToArray();
            foreach(var item in mySeq1)
    Console.Write(item.ToString() + " ");
        } 
    }
}
```

Produces the output:

```
Hello, world!
-2 -1 0
```

Is there already an inbuilt method that I can use to get the python's output ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second argument of [`Enumerable.Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) specifies the **count** of the elements to be generated, not the stop value.

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
int half_window = 2;
var mySeq1 = Enumerable.Range(-2, 5).ToArray();
//                                ^
foreach(var item in mySeq1)
    Console.Write(item.ToString() + " ");
```

Output:

```
Hello, world!
-2 -1 0 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as cubrr says, the second parameter works slightly differently - if you wanted to write your own method that works exactly like the Python equivalent, you could use:

```
public static class MyEnumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> Range(int start, int stop)
    {
        for (int i = start; i < stop; i++)
            yield return i;
    }
}
```

Used as:

```
var result = MyEnumerable.Range(-2, 3); // -2, -1, 0, 1, 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Enumerable.Range works like this

Enumerable.Range(STARTVALUE, How many to count up)

Example
`Enumerable.Range(6, 10)` Would produce

```
arr[6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
```

that is, 10 elements starting from

If you want to count up to a surden point you'll have to write your own functionality. Something alike

```
MakeRange(int st, int end)
{
    var range = st < 0 ? Math.Abs(st) + end + 1 : end-st;

    return Enumerable.Range(st, range);
}
```

Hope this helped you

Answer (score 0):

C#'s `Enumerable.Range` takes a start value and a *count* - the number of elements to return, not an end value like in python.  To get the equivalent return value to python, you need to call it as:

```
Enumerable.Range(start, end-start);
```

So in your case, the call would be

```
Enumerable.Range(-2, (2+1) - (-2));
```

which is the same as saying

```
Enumerable.Range(-2, 5);
```

The only caveat is you need to be careful that `end-start` is not negative, otherwise `Enumerable.Range` will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.